# Send Proactive Email in the Botframework C# SDK

Tags: c#, email, botframework

I have a bot with LUIS integrated, I've emulated it for basic text responses such as responding to a greeting, with a greeting back.

I now want to add an additional message to the NoneIntent so that when a message sent to the bot is classed as being of the NoneIntent, the bot emails a mailbox (the helpdesk) as it's call to action alongside responding with a text response.

So far I have:

```
 [LuisIntent("None")]
        public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            //Send call to action email here

            // The text response given back to the user in the bot channel
            await context.PostAsync("I'm sorry, I don't understand your question :(");

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To send a proactive email message in C# via your bot you'll need to set up the [email channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-email?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) for your bot and then set up a new email message (along with connector) in your code:

```
var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BotId"]}", id: $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BotEmail"]}".ToLower()); //taken from the email channel on your bot config
var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: "Name", id: $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserEmail"]}"); //the email account you are sending your messages to
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(@"https://email.botframework.com/", DateTime.MaxValue);
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("https://email.botframework.com/" ));
var conversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);
IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.From = botAccount;
message.Recipient = userAccount;
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId.Id);
message.Text = "This is the content text of an email!";
message.Locale = "en-Us";


try
{
    await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
}
catch (ErrorResponseException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: ", e.StackTrace);
}
```

A new conversation is required because you don't have a context saved to send a new email to if you aren't responding directly to an email from your helpdesk account.

Comment: This can be a solution, but I am not sure that using the Email channel is the solution here. The OP can simply use an email sending solution, as the purpose is only to log the "unanswered" case and display a response to the user

Comment: That makes sense, this would be the solution for doing it within the context of the bot itself if that's what OP really wants. That said, it'd probably make sense to have an alternative with just sending an email normally in C# without utilizing the channel.

Comment: You're right. One main point is that Email channel needs an Office365 account, whereas sending the email via code is possible with many email providers.